Boxes.py: сохранение сгенерированной модели в svg
Boxes.py - это библиотека для генерации коробок для лазерной резки. Я с python почти не знаком, сижу разбираю простейший пример. Склонировал себе, установил зависимости. Мой пример:
from boxes.generators import abox

def create_abox():
  # Создание "абокс" с заданным содержимым
  box = abox.ABox()

  # параметры коробки
  box.length = 100  # Длина коробки
  box.width = 100   # Ширина коробки
  box.height = 100  # Высота коробки
  box.thickness = 3  # Толщина материала

  return box

if __name__ == "__main__":

  # Создание "абокс"
  abox = create_abox()

  # Генерация содержимого SVG
  svg_content = abox.render()

  # Сохранение содержимого SVG в файл
  with open("box_output.svg", "w") as f:
    f.write(svg_content)

  print("Коробка сохранена в box_output.svg")

И получаю ошибки:
svg_content = abox.render()
x, y, h = self.x, self.y, self.h
AttributeError: 'ABox' object has no attribute 'x'

И на этом пока застрял

Ну там нужны эти параметры, да. Что это такое вы сами должны знать. Видимо x и y это какие-то координаты. h не знаю что это )  Посмотрите исходник этого abox, может что-то понятнее станет: https://github.com/florianfesti/boxes/blob/master/boxes/generators/abox.py

Скорее всего нужно просто не length, width, height указывать, а как раз эти x, y, h

Вообще это они конечно "хорошо" придумали - не передавать именованные параметры при создании класса, а прописывать атрибуты снаружи.
